# setting AutoPlay property of jssor slider dynamically on button click

Tags: javascript, onclick, slider, jssor, autoplay

Hi I am working onintegrating jssor slider in my application.I have used a basic version of slider showing an array of images to which user can swipe through from right to left.

```
 /* Gallery items carousel slider - start */
    var options = {
        $StartIndex: 0,                 //[Optional] Index of slide to display when initialize, default value is 0

        $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
        $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
        $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
        $PauseOnHover: 3,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
        $Loop: 0,                                      // Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
        $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
        $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
        //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
        //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
        $SlideSpacing: 5,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
        $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
        $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
        $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
        $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
        $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

        $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
            $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
            $AutoCenter: 3,                             //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
            $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
            $SpacingX: 1,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
            $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 5,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                            //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
            $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            $DisableDrag: true                              //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
        }
    };
    var arrImg = ["01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg", "04.jpg"];

    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (parentWidth) {
            var sliderWidth = parentWidth;

            //keep the slider width no more than 600
            sliderWidth = Math.min(sliderWidth, 600);

            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(sliderWidth);
        }
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
    ScaleSlider();

    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);

$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

1) I have a button on my page tapping on which i need to set the AutoPlay property of this slider to be set to true to enable auto scroll of images. And tapping on it the again should stop the autoplay of jssor slider.

```
$('.StartSlideshowBtn')
    .click(
            function () {
                slider1_container
                if (options.$AutoPlay == false) {
                    options.$AutoPlay = true;
                }
                else {
                    options.$AutoPlay = false;
                }
                jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

                        });
```

I tried setting it but i am not able to access the object of jssor slider in it .
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Gallery items carousel slider - start */
var options = {
    $StartIndex: 0,                 //[Optional] Index of slide to display when initialize, default value is 0

    $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
    $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $PauseOnHover: 3,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
    $Loop: 0,                                      // Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
    //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
    //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
    $SlideSpacing: 5,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
    $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
    $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
    $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

    $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
        $AutoCenter: 3,                             //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
        $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 1,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
        $Cols: 5,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
        $Align: 0,                            //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
        $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
        $DisableDrag: true                              //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
    }
};
var arrImg = ["01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg", "04.jpg"];

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth) {
        var sliderWidth = parentWidth;

        //keep the slider width no more than 600
        sliderWidth = Math.min(sliderWidth, 600);

        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(sliderWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);

$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);

$('.StartSlideshowBtn').click(function () {
    if (jssor_slider1.$IsAutoPlaying()) {
        jssor_slider1.$Pause();
    }
    else {
        jssor_slider1.$Play();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot ,You saved my day. It works great. But out of curosity i have one thing to ask . I tried code snippets                                             var sliderObj = document.getElementById("slider1_container");      console.log("SLIDE AUTOPLAY IS " + sliderObj.$AutoPlay);                       if (sliderObj.$AutoPlay == false)
     {sliderObj.$AutoPlay = true; }                        else{sliderObj..$AutoPlay = false;} Will this code work ?

Comment: You can read nothing from sliderObj.$AutoPlay. The correct call is sliderObj.$IsAutoPlaying()

Comment: I have this requirement to load slider with images from database and as the images scrolls through in slideshow, i should update the label below for that particular image. Can you please tell me any event i can use to assign value to label on every image that comes. like any event that fires as the index of my slider changes ? Thanks

Comment: When the index of slide change, the $EVT_PARK will fire.